# Which tool / technology: System management for databases and dependent services

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, oracle, powershell, windows-service

I'm looking for advice on how to enable our team to take down and re-start our company systems for maintenance purposes.

The scenario includes

- several Oracle db machines
- several MS SQL Server machines with multiple instances
- windows services (IIS etc.)
- BizTalk EAI solution
- Apache and Tomcat instances
- lots of scheduled tasks

on win2003 and win2008 machines (physical and virtual).

The main focus is on capture all **dependencies** between said databases and services and tasks connecting to them.

At the moment an enterprise class solution is not an option.

We are considering developing a solution driven by **PowerShell** scripts but I hope for some more suggestions.

---

**In other words:** *What technology should I use to develop a flexible solution that will allow me to stop service A, B and C on machine D in the right order and disable task E on machine F when taking down database X?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use powershell to manage SQL Server and various applications based on SQL Server, so I can definitely recommend using it.  I don't know any specifics of managing Oracle with it, but I know IIS, Windows Services, SQL Server, scheduled tasks are all pretty straight-forward to manage with powershell scripts.

Comment: It's not so much handling the individual items like services and databases as being able to model the dependencies. On SO I was pointed to http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake/ which looks very promising. See answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837247/which-tool-technology-system-management-for-databases-and-dependent-services/2837348#2837348 for details.

Answer (score 0):

SCOM - System Center Operations Manager. Check it out ;)

Comment: This would fall into the enterprise class solution category which is not an option at this point.

Comment: SCE - System Center Essentials.